# GCS Access Log stopped to be stored

Tags: google-cloud-storage, access-log

I'm using GCS.

I set the access log setting according to the following instructions and I was getting logs correctly.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

However, since 11 hours ago, access log has no longer been stored in the specified gcs bucket.

We haven't changed anything.

Also we checked the logging status by the following command and it's ok.
`gsutil logging get gs://example-bucket`

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: We haven't received any report which has widely affected the customers. However, If the issue still persists, I recommend to report it via your support package (if you have any) or via a PRIVATE [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491246&template=1161282) and provide us with your project id there, so that we would be able to dig into the issue.

Comment: Thank you for checking the question. I finally got all the access logs after almost 20 hours after the time the log was supposed to be recorded. Now I don't see this much time lag.

Comment: @tera_mx hey how did you fix the problem?